# Завершение работы сервера

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Имеется служба WCF, которая хостится в консольном приложении, также имеется клиент созданный на WPF. По запросу клиента необходимо сделать следующие вещи:

1. Закрыть консольное приложение сервера
2. Запустить другой сервер(другое приложение)

Каким образом это можно сделать?

**Upd** Пока клиент выполняет прочие операции сервер выполняет команду `ReadLine`

Comment: из консоли с сервером запускаете клон, и закрываете консоль. а клон продолжает работу.

Comment: _"сервер выполняет команду ReadLine"_ -- сервер должен отвечать на запросы. а его хост должен ждать команды.

Comment: консоль находится на удалении и соответственно руками закрыть консоль нет возможности, а `ReadLine` в данной ситуации не дает серверу закончить работу сразу после запуска(в это время он отвечает на команды клиента

Comment: в классе сервера должно быть событие. на него прдписывается хост. когда на сервер приходи - ой,все. то сервер посылает событие. хост его ловит и закрывает консоль. или перед этим запускает отдельный процесс - свой клон.

Comment: Эээ... А зачем давать клиенту право перегружать сервер? Пахнет костылём. Вы не думали может в качестве альтернативы пофиксить утечки памяти в сервере?

Comment: а с чего вы решили что есть какие-то утечки памяти? И не перегружать, а запускать другое приложение сервера, на 1 машине 2 приложения должны работать по очереди, оба как сервер для одного клиента

Comment: с событиями получилось сделать, спасибо, оформите пожалуйста это как ответ